# TensorFlow demo has stopped on Android TFlite

Tags: android, tensorflow, machine-learning, android-gradle-plugin, deep-learning

I am following Tensorflow for poets 2(https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets-2/#7) session8(Run the customised app).So far, I have successfully ran the demo by Google for Android, but when I train custom flowers  data and try to run the demo again by following session 8 in the tutorial in which I replace output name by final result as follows:

```
private static final String OUTPUT_NAME = "final_result";
```

I am getting error :

```
    02/08 20:48:30: Launching tfmobile
$ adb install-multiple -r -t C:\Users\Ajinkya\Tensorflow_for_poets\tensorflow-for-poets-2\android\tfmobile\gradleBuild\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_7.apk C:\Users\Ajinkya\Tensorflow_for_poets\tensorflow-for-poets-2\android\tfmobile\gradleBuild\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_2.apk C:\Users\Ajinkya\Tensorflow_for_poets\tensorflow-for-poets-2\android\tfmobile\gradleBuild\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_6.apk C:\Users\Ajinkya\Tensorflow_for_poets\tensorflow-for-poets-2\android\tfmobile\gradleBuild\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_8.apk C:\Users\Ajinkya\Tensorflow_for_poets\tensorflow-for-poets-2\android\tfmobile\gradleBuild\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_9.apk C:\Users\Ajinkya\Tensorflow_for_poets\tensorflow-for-poets-2\android\tfmobile\gradleBuild\intermediates\split-apk\debug\dep\dependencies.apk C:\Users\Ajinkya\Tensorflow_for_poets\tensorflow-for-poets-2\android\tfmobile\gradleBuild\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_5.apk C:\Users\Ajinkya\Tensorflow_for_poets\tensorflow-for-poets-2\android\tfmobile\gradleBuild\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_4.apk C:\Users\Ajinkya\Tensorflow_for_poets\tensorflow-for-poets-2\android\tfmobile\gradleBuild\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_3.apk C:\Users\Ajinkya\Tensorflow_for_poets\tensorflow-for-poets-2\android\tfmobile\gradleBuild\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_1.apk C:\Users\Ajinkya\Tensorflow_for_poets\tensorflow-for-poets-2\android\tfmobile\gradleBuild\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_0.apk C:\Users\Ajinkya\Tensorflow_for_poets\tensorflow-for-poets-2\android\tfmobile\gradleBuild\outputs\apk\debug\tfmobile-debug.apk 
Split APKs installed
$ adb shell am start -n "org.tensorflow.demo/org.tensorflow.demo.ClassifierActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Client not ready yet..Connected to process 32013 on device motorola-moto_g__4_-ZY223WW626
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
D/tensorflow: CameraActivity: onCreate org.tensorflow.demo.ClassifierActivity@3c0dd38
D/tensorflow: CameraActivity: onStart org.tensorflow.demo.ClassifierActivity@3c0dd38
D/tensorflow: CameraActivity: onResume org.tensorflow.demo.ClassifierActivity@3c0dd38
I/Adreno: QUALCOMM build                   : 7d18700, I8ee426a9a2
          Build Date                       : 10/07/16
          OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: XE031.09.00.03
          Local Branch                     : mybranch22308589
          Remote Branch                    : quic/LA.BR.1.3.6_rb1.6
          Remote Branch                    : NONE
          Reconstruct Branch               : NOTHING
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
I/CameraManagerGlobal: Connecting to camera service
I/tensorflow: CameraConnectionFragment: Desired size: 640x480, min size: 480x480
I/tensorflow: CameraConnectionFragment: Valid preview sizes: [1280x960, 1280x720, 960x720, 960x540, 864x480, 720x480, 640x480]
I/tensorflow: CameraConnectionFragment: Rejected preview sizes: [768x432, 320x240, 176x144]
I/tensorflow: CameraConnectionFragment: Exact size match found.
I/TensorFlowImageClassifier: Reading labels from: labels.txt
I/TensorFlowInferenceInterface: Checking to see if TensorFlow native methods are already loaded
E/art: No implementation found for long org.tensorflow.contrib.android.RunStats.allocate() (tried Java_org_tensorflow_contrib_android_RunStats_allocate and Java_org_tensorflow_contrib_android_RunStats_allocate__)
I/TensorFlowInferenceInterface: TensorFlow native methods not found, attempting to load via tensorflow_inference
I/TensorFlowInferenceInterface: Successfully loaded TensorFlow native methods (RunStats error may be ignored)
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: org.tensorflow.demo, PID: 32013
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to load model from 'file:///android_asset/graph.pb'
                      at org.tensorflow.contrib.android.TensorFlowInferenceInterface.<init>(TensorFlowInferenceInterface.java:100)
                      at org.tensorflow.demo.TensorFlowImageClassifier.create(TensorFlowImageClassifier.java:103)
                      at org.tensorflow.demo.ClassifierActivity.onPreviewSizeChosen(ClassifierActivity.java:130)
                      at org.tensorflow.demo.CameraActivity$1.onPreviewSizeChosen(CameraActivity.java:159)
                      at org.tensorflow.demo.CameraConnectionFragment.setUpCameraOutputs(CameraConnectionFragment.java:421)
                      at org.tensorflow.demo.CameraConnectionFragment.openCamera(CameraConnectionFragment.java:428)
                      at org.tensorflow.demo.CameraConnectionFragment.access$000(CameraConnectionFragment.java:64)
                      at org.tensorflow.demo.CameraConnectionFragment$1.onSurfaceTextureAvailable(CameraConnectionFragment.java:95)
                      at android.view.TextureView.getHardwareLayer(TextureView.java:387)
                      at android.view.TextureView.draw(TextureView.java:325)
                      at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16065)
                      at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16849)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3768)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3554)
                      at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16060)
                      at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16849)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3768)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3554)
                      at android.view.View.draw(View.java:17086)
                      at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16065)
                      at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16849)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3768)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3554)
                      at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16060)
                      at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16849)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3768)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3554)
                      at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16060)
                      at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16849)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3768)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3554)
                      at android.view.View.draw(View.java:17086)
                      at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.draw(DecorView.java:751)
                      at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16065)
                      at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:657)
                      at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:663)
                      at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:771)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2808)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2616)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2223)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1258)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6348)
                      at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:871)
                      at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:683)
                      at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:619)
                      at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:857)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
E/AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.io.IOException: Not a valid TensorFlow Graph serialization: NodeDef mentions attr 'dilations' not in Op<name=Conv2D; signature=input:T, filter:T -> output:T; attr=T:type,allowed=[DT_HALF, DT_FLOAT]; attr=strides:list(int); attr=use_cudnn_on_gpu:bool,default=true; attr=padding:string,allowed=["SAME", "VALID"]; attr=data_format:string,default="NHWC",allowed=["NHWC", "NCHW"]>; NodeDef: MobilenetV1/MobilenetV1/Conv2d_0/convolution = Conv2D[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NHWC", dilations=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding="SAME", strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], use_cudnn_on_gpu=true](input, MobilenetV1/Conv2d_0/weights). (Check whether your GraphDef-interpreting binary is up to date with your GraphDef-generating binary.).
                      at org.tensorflow.contrib.android.TensorFlowInferenceInterface.loadGraph(TensorFlowInferenceInterface.java:392)
                      at org.tensorflow.contrib.android.TensorFlowInferenceInterface.<init>(TensorFlowInferenceInterface.java:96)
                        ... 52 more
Application terminated.
```

And the application is terminated, what should I do to resolve this

Answer (score 0):

This isn't TensorFlow Lite -- it's tfmobile.

For TensorFlow Lite, follow this codelab: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets-2-tflite/index.html#0

If you want to get it working with tfmobile (though I would recommend using TFLite), then take a look here for the specific error you're hitting: [Tensorflow Mobile App: Not a valid TensorFlow Graph serialization: NodeDef mentions attr 'dilations' not in Op](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47851049/tensorflow-mobile-app-not-a-valid-tensorflow-graph-serialization-nodedef-menti)